# Can someone help me in determining why if construct at line No 17 is not functional in following Solidity code?

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title FourthContract
 * @dev Exploring conditionals and loops
 */
contract FourthContract {

    uint[] public numbers = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];

    function countOddNumbers() public view returns (uint) {
        uint count = 0;

        for(uint i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            ***if (isOddNumber(numbers[i])) {
                count = count + numbers[i];
            }***
        }
        return count;
    }

    function isOddNumber (uint _number) public view returns(bool) {
        if (_number % 2 == 1) { 
           return true;
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct

here are few tweaks. I've added an odd number to the array because all are even and thus countOddNumbers returns 0.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title FourthContract
 * @dev Exploring conditionals and loops
 */
contract FourthContract {

    uint[] public numbers = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,11];

    function countOddNumbers() public view returns (uint) {
        uint count = 0;

        for(uint i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           if (isOddNumber(numbers[i])) {
                count++;
           }
        }
        return count;
    }

    function isOddNumber (uint _number) public pure returns(bool) {
        if (_number % 2 == 1) { 
           return true;
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```